# haml data Boolean Attributes

Tags: haml

I am trying to render a data boolean attribute like this

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'email-mobile', :'data-roadie-ignore' => true
```

When I render the html file with mailer preview I inspect the css and I can spot the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/ema...." data-roadie-ignore="true">
```

Shouldn't be displaying

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/ema...." data-roadie-ignore> ?
```

I have tried to update the haml.rb file

```
Haml::Template.options[:format] = :html5
Haml::Options.defaults[:format] = :html5
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the output of the `stylesheet_link_tag` method, rather than what Haml generates. I don’t know if Rails provides a way to control the output of that method.